# SQL Linq: get single instance of nested DB class

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have the following model

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<B> BData { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Big class with lots of data
}
```

My *DbContext* looks like:

```
public class EmpSrvDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> AData { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

I have a getter which should return *B*. Currently I'm trying to do it as follows:

```
B Get(int nAId, string sBName)
{
    A foundA = m_dbCtx.AData
        .Where(obj => obj.Id == nAId)
        .Include(obj => obj.BData)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    return foundA.BData.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.Name == sBName);
}
```

I believe this is inefficient, because for found *A* class I load all its *B* objects and since *B* is a big class this is heavy.

Is there a way how to obtain only the requested *B* object of *A* object, without including/loading all *B* objects?

Thanks, Csaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to load A into memory, you can find B straight away:

```
B Get(int nAId, string sBName)
{
    B foundB = (
        from a in m_dbCtx.AData
        where a.Id == nAId
        from b in a.BData
        where b.Name == sBName
        select b
    )
    .FirstOrDefault();

    return foundB;
}
```

Or

```
B Get(int nAId, string sBName)
{
    B foundB = m_dbCtx.AData
        .Where(a => a.Id == nAId)
        .SelectMany(a => a.BData)
        .Where(b => b.Name == sBName)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return foundB;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you write this using method based Linq syntax. I do know this kind of syntax too much :-) Especially I don't know what is the "from" equivalent...

Comment: Wow, SelectMany is the key! Makes sense. Thank you very much! :-)